# Crystal Report Report Footer Issue?

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

There is a field called "Total cost" for each Group(which is Dept in this case).I have summed up the individual values of this field "Total Cost" in the group footer for each group, which give me aggregate total cost of each group at the group footer .Now I want to summarize the report with just Dept name i.e group name and the aggregate total (sum of total cost field of that group) in the report.
Could anyone please furnish some sample code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Care to explain - from what you wrote, I can't understand, what is you problem. You already have totals for Dept? Are 'Dept' and 'Dept name' same things? What is issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is group summary in report footer i.e. you want to display all department names along with total cost for the department at the end of report - right? AFAIK, only way to achieve this would be to use a sub-report in the report footer.

You may use the same query/dataset for your sub-report,  have same group(s) but no details section, only group summary fields and no page-breaks on groups. Alternate way is to use different query that would give the summarized output (i.e. grouping at database level).